# Grunt leaving HTML blank

Tags: javascript, html, gruntjs

I have a `/dist` folder properly populated with `index.html` and a `static` folder, but when I load the webpage, I get a blank `index.html` page, without any content inserted via js.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

  <title>People</title>

  <!-- Application styles. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.min.css" type="text/css">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/static/img/favicon.ico" />

  <!-- include bootstrap and font-awesome css files -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- include bootstrap-tags css files -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bower_components/bootstrap-tags/dist/css/bootstrap-tags.css"/>
  <!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.7.1/bootstrap-tagsinput.css"/-->

  <!-- include slick css files -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick-theme.css"/>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header-area">

    </div>

    <div id="content">

    </div>

    <div id="modal-holder">

    </div>

  </div>


  <!-- Application source. -->
  <script src="/static/js/source.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Google Analytics -->
  <script>
  window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
  </script>
  <script async src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
  <!-- End Google Analytics -->

</body>
</html>
```

Like I said, there's a `source.min.js` and Chrome even finds it fine.

[image]

---

What am I missing here?

---

**Update**
Here's my `Gruntfile.js`

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Configuration
  grunt.initConfig({
    /*------- JS Hint -------*/
    jshint: {
      files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'src/**/*.js', '!src/manual_tp/**/*.js' ,'!src/manual_tp/*.js', '!src/models/analytics/analytics.js'],
      options: {
        globals: {
          jQuery: true
        }
      }
    },
    /*------- Clean -------*/
    clean: ["dist/"],
    /*------- Process HTML -------*/
    processhtml: {
      release: {
        files: {
          'dist/index.html': ['index.html']
        },
        options: {
            process: true
        }
      }
    },
    /*------- Copy -------*/
    copy: {
      release: {
        files: [
        {src:['static/**'], dest:'dist/'}
        ]
      }
    },
    /*------- RequireJS -------*/
    requirejs: {
      production: {
        options: {
          baseUrl: "src/",
          mainConfigFile: 'src/config.js',
          generateSourceMaps: true,
          out: "dist/static/js/source.min.js",
          optimize: "uglify2",
          name: "almond",
          wrap: true,
          preserveLicenseComments: false,
          useStrict: true,
          findNestedDependencies: true
        }
      }
    },
    /*------- Less -------*/
    less: {
      run: {
        options: {
          paths: ["src/less"]
        },
        files: {
          "dist/static/css/styles.css": "src/less/index.less"
        }
      }
    },
    /*------- CSS Min -------*/
    cssmin: {
      release: {
        files: {
          "dist/static/css/styles.min.css": ["dist/static/css/styles.css"]
        }
      }
    },
    /*------- Server -------*/
    server: {
      options: {
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        port: 80
      },
      development: {},
      release: {
        options: {
          prefix: "dist"
        }
      }
    },
    /*------- Grunt Watch -------*/
    /* If any of the js/html/less files change, update the application */
    watch: {
      js: {
        files: ['src/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['requirejs']
      },
      html: {
        files: ['src/templates/**/*html'],
        tasks: ['requirejs']
      },
      less: {
        files: ['src/less/**/*less'],
        tasks: ['less', 'cssmin']
      },
      images: {
        files: ['src/images/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
        tasks: ['imagemin']
      }
    },
    /*------- Grunt Image Compression -------*/
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          optimizationLevel: 3
        },
        files: [{
           expand: true,
           cwd: 'src/images',
           src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif,ico}'],
           dest: 'dist/static/img/'
        }]
      }
    }

  });

// Load NPM Tasks
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-processhtml');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bbb-server');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');

// Build
grunt.registerTask('build', [
  'clean',
  'jshint',
  'processhtml',
  'copy',
  'requirejs',
  'less',
  'cssmin',
  'imagemin'
  ]);

grunt.registerTask('serve', ['server']); // Start local server on the main directory
grunt.registerTask('servedist', ['server:release']); // Start local server on the dist directory

// Default grunt command
grunt.registerTask('default', [
  'build'
  ]);

};
```

Comment: I don't see the source.min.js in the image posted, unless that was intentional? The only reason I can think of JS downright stopping, is a JS error. Nothing showing up in your console in Chrome?

Comment: Nothing at all in the console which is baffling me. And there's also a js map file so I'm guessing chrome is just breaking source.min up so you can debug easier

Comment: Hmm, so it's generating and loading the js file in the HTML file. And the generated JS contents look fine when previewing the response in the Network tab? Also I assume your using a legit HTTP server and not strait up viewing the html file in your browser.

Comment: Yep. Nginx. The only thing in the inspector is the actual html code in `index.html`. It's not using any of the js to fill in the code. Network tab responses look fine. I'm only using nginx though. I don't need another server handling it right?

Comment: Nginx is perfectly fine. Without actually seeing any code it's hard to pin point the issue.  I would at least post your grunt file for starters.

Comment: Also some source code too of backbone. Not a backbone expert, but it could also be an error on how your binding your dom elements together with your js.

Comment: @ajm113 added my `Gruntfile.js`. Let me know if there's anything in there that wold help. Still haven't found a solution yet.